# How to detect a discord message being edited (but not updated)?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm using Node and Discord.JS, trying to see if there's a way to differentiate between types of edits whenever a message is edited so a bot can tease the user for editing their message. The function works well so far, and is as follows:

```
let responses = ["some", "responses"];
bot.on('messageUpdate', ( message ) => {
     let result = responses[Math.floor(Math.random()*(responses.length)-1)]
     message.channel.send(result);
})
```

However, this detects *all* message updates, including say a link updating to have an embed. Is there any way to differentiate between a deliberate user edit and a message being updated with an embed through event listeners, or will I need to make a workaround with an if..else statement?

Answer (score 1):

To check when message is edited, You'll be required to use the `messageUpdate` event listener.

In the `messageUpdate` event, there is 2 parameters. (`oldMessage`, `newMessage`) [Learn More](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageUpdate)

Then, you can check the content of the `oldMessage` & `newMessage` parameters by using the `.content` property.

Example of code:

```js
client.on("messageUpdate", (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    if(oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) return // Will do nothing if the content of oldMessage is equals to newMessage's content
    // Do here your stuff
})
```

I hope I helped you!

Comment: A check for whether the message was sent/edited by a bot should also be in place.

Comment: This seems to have worked, but now im running into an issue where the result that i have from my results array wont send, with the error of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel')". If I leave "message" out of the parameters being passed, it says that message is undefined, but with it passed it doesn't seem to be able to read the properties of it. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this, i have not found an answer as I had hoped ;(